# Convert an integer to a 2 byte Hex value in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, int, hex, data-conversion

For a tkinter GUI, I must read in a Hex address in the form of '0x00' to set an I2C address. The way I am currently doing it is by reading the input as a string, converting the string to an integer, then converting that integer to an actual Hex value as shown in the partial code below:

GUI initialization:

```
self.I2CAddress=StringVar()
self.I2CAddress.set("0x00") #Sets Default value of '0x00'
Label(frame, text="Address: ").grid(row=5, column=4)
Entry(frame, textvariable=self.I2CAddress).grid(row=5, column=5)
```

Then inside the function:

```
addr = self.I2CAddress.get()   
addrint = int(addr, 16)  
addrhex = hex(addrint)
```

This works for most values, but my issue is that if I enter a small Hex value string such as '0x01', it converts to the proper integer of 1, but then that is converted to a Hex value of 0x1 instead of 0x01.

I am an EE and have very limited programming experience, so any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use the [`format()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#format):

```
format(addrint, '#04x')
```

This formats the input value as a 2 digit hexadecimal string with leading zeros to make up the length, and `#` includes the 'standard prefix', `0x` in this case. Note that the width of 4 includes that prefix. `x` produces lower-case hex strings; use `X` if you need uppercase.

Demo:

```
>>> for i in range(8, 12):
...     print format(i, '#04x')
... 
0x08
0x09
0x0a
0x0b
```

Comment: You answered so quickly I have to wait a few minutes before it allows me, but I absolutely will

Comment: You can just use `{:#02x}` instead of the explicit `0x`. The `#` will add the "standard prefix", which for hex numbers is `0x`. (This also works the same way with %-formatting, and C `printf`, and POSIX command-line `printf`, etc.)

Comment: @abarnert: Cool, I was *not* aware of the `#` prefix option.

Comment: @abarnert: Slight snag: `#` **removes** the leading zeros again. That, to me, looks like a bug, it appears as if the width is ignored altogether.

Comment: @abarnert: ah, no, the field width includes the prefix.

Comment: Right, sorry, you want `{:#04x}`. Whenever I actually write code for this (in C or Python) I type 10, 6, or 4 without thinking, but whenever I explain it to someone else, I tell them to use 8, 4, or 2, and they run into the exact same thing you did. You'd think I'd learn one of these decades…

Comment: @abarnert: With the `#` prefix you can just use the `format()` function and completely dispense with the string templating altogether.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, For format(-1,'04X')  the output is -01 instead of FF

Comment: @Nazar: Python integers are unbounded, unlike C signed integers. -01 is the *correct* output.